# How does seekg() effect getline() when past the end of the file?

Tags: c++, fstream

If I use `seekg()` to seek past the end of the file, does `std::getline()` change the `std::string` passed to it?

```
//readWrite is an fstream object.
//fileLineLength is an int, every line in the file will be the same length.
string  RWDN::read(size_t number){
    string line = "";
    readWrite.seekg(number * fileLineLength);
    getline(readWrite, line);
    return line;
}
```

Will that return some random stuff, or will `line` remain an empty string?

Comment: You could just try it and see what happens. But if you are already at EOF and try to read a string, why do you expect it to return garbage? There is nothing to read, so nothing to append to the `std::string`

Comment: I am pretty sure it won't I'm just not sure if it still tries to read something though.

Comment: once you are at EOF, there is nothing to read. The stream's `eofbit` flag will be set. If you are worried about returning garbage, then simply pay attention to the stream state: `if (!getline(readWrite, line)) return "";`

Comment: ok thats what I was wondering. thank you.